# Dynamic Sender Profiles are not appearing in A/B Test

Tags: marketing-cloud, ab-testing

Currently we are using dynamic sender profiles to send an email (via user initiated sends,automation studio & Journey builder ) to different customers across 200 countries.

We are launching a new product. So would like to use A/B Test on the content of email.

But I couldn't able to choose the dynamic sender profile in A/B Test.

I have also got an update from SF Support that it not available.
[image]
I have added this in Idea - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U4cfQAC

Is anyone experience this issue before? Also wanted to check what is the better way if we want to A/B Test via dynamic sender profile?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I just checked and am able to use a dynamic sender profile in an A/B test - can you check if you are able to choose them elsewhere?

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, Thank you so much for checking into your account. Yes, i can able to use dynamic profile in all the places (user initiated, automation studio, journey builder) but not on A/B Test. I have also checked with support. They said that dynamic sender profile is not available under A/B test. (Attached the screenshot of SF support response). Its weird that why they would respond when something is available. Do i need to enable some setting? Am using S10 instance, may i know which instance are using?